# PHP Sanitise Data

Tags: php, mysql

Can't seem to sanitise php data

```
<?php
$lastname  = "O'Reilly";
echo $lastname;
$_lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($lastname);
echo $_lastname ;
?>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: `mysql_` is removed from PHP. and can you explain the problem? like what you except and what you get and errors if any?

Comment: Your code as posted, doesn't do anything really, except generate errors.

Comment: I would like to be able to replace the ' with \' for inserting into mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_real_escape_string()` won't do anything all by itself. You have to have an open connection to a database.

However, all the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. You should look into Prepared Statements instead.

Comment: *"You should look into PDO instead."* - With a prepared statement of course. Using PDO on its own won't protect against an SQL injection. *Just saying* ;-)